# How to programmatically give s3 bucket permission to invoke lambda?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, boto3

### What I am doing

Currently I am trying to dynamically create an `event` on a `bucket` to call a lambda function, whenever a trigger like `s3:ObjectCreated:*` or `s3:ObjectRemoved:*` occurs.

### My current code

I have the following code

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('s3',
                      aws_access_key_id="...",
                      aws_secret_access_key="...",
                      region_name="us-east-1")


response = client.put_bucket_notification(
    Bucket='my_test_bucket',
    NotificationConfiguration={
    'CloudFunctionConfiguration': {
            'Id': event_name,
            'Events': [
                's3:ObjectCreated:*',
                's3:ObjectRemoved:*',
            ],
            'CloudFunction': 'arn:aws:lambda:...',

        }
    }
)
```

### My problem

However, when I try to run the code, I get the following error

```
An error occurred (InvalidArgument) when calling the PutBucketNotification 
operation: Unable to validate the following destination configurations

Not authorized to invoke function [arn:aws:lambda:...]
```

### My question

How do I programmatically give `my_test_bucket` permission to run `arn:aws:lambda:...`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please refer to the official documentation, the method you are using is deprecated and while it is maintained for backwards compatibility, it may not function as expected.  See [here](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.put_bucket_notification) for more information; you should be using `PutBucketNotificationConfiguration` which is [bucket_notification.put()](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.BucketNotification.put).

Nonetheless, the error that you are seeing is:

`Not authorized to invoke function [arn:aws:lambda:...]`

This is because when your Lambda executes, the service invoking it needs permission to invoke it; you simply need to give S3 permission to invoke your Lambda. You do this by creating a Resource Policy for your Lambda.

In Python you're going to do this something like this:

```
 client = boto3.client('lambda')
 response = client.add_permission(
     FunctionName='arn:aws:lambda:...',
     StatementId='LambdaInvoke',
     Action='lambda:InvokeFunction',
     Principal='s3.amazonaws.com',
     SourceArn='arn:aws:s3:::my_test_bucket',
     SourceAccount='123456789012'
 )
```

Don't forget to replace the `function-name` with your functions ARN, as well as the `source-arn` to be your S3 buckets ARN, and `source-account` to be the source account number.

An alternative way, if you wanted to do it from the CLI, you can do it like this:

```
aws lambda add-permission --function-name arn:aws:lambda:... --principal s3.amazonaws.com --statement-id S3EventTrigger --action "lambda:InvokeFunction" --source-arn arn:aws:s3:::my_test_bucket --source-account 123456789012
```

Both of these methods will attach a resource policy, that looks like the policy below, to your Lambda, allowing your S3 bucket to invoke it.

```
{"Policy" : "{"Version":"2012-10-17","Id":"default","Statement":[{"Sid":"S3EventTrigger","Effect":"Allow","Principal":{"Service":"s3.amazonaws.com"},"Action":"lambda:InvokeFunction","Resource":"arn:aws:lambda:...","Condition":{"StringEquals":{"AWS:SourceAccount":"123456789012"},"ArnLike":{"AWS:SourceArn":"arn:aws:s3:::my_test_bucket"}}}]}" ,
"RevisionId" : "999a9999-99ab-9999-a9a9-9999999a999a"}
```

Comment: Is it possible to configure the lambda function permission to let anyone use it? As opposed to just a specific S3 bucket?

Answer (score 2):

I recommand you to read the official document https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/access-control-resource-based.html

As it said, "**When you use an AWS service to invoke your function, you grant permission in a statement on a resource-based policy.**"

Also, here is an official tutorial of lambda with S3 https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example.html.

As it said, you can grant permission by running command in cli:

```sh
$ aws lambda add-permission --function-name your-function-name --principal s3.amazonaws.com \
--statement-id some-unique-id --action "lambda:InvokeFunction" \
--source-arn arn:aws:s3:::sourcebucket \
--source-account bucket-owner-account-id
```